# Returning values from saved row

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP code, I save a record like this:-

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO levels (levelName)
                 VALUES ('" . $_POST["levelName"][0] . "')");
```

And this works fine.

In the table 'levels', there is an auto-incrementing PK field called "ID".  How would I go about returning/echoing the value of that field when the record is saved to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quoting from the following reference:**

### **How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row**

If you insert a record into a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column, you can obtain the value stored into that column by calling the mysql_insert_id() function.

@ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

-

### Example

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "peter", "abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("test_db",$con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Børge','Refsnes','Sandnes','17')";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysql_insert_id();

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

from: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_insert_id.asp

Answer (score 1):

use

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

function

if using mysqli use something like this

```
$mysqli->insert_id
```